# Criteria query for fetching the data after particular date and time

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I am using the criteria  query as follows:I want to fetch the reservations after  the time  and date I have passed.but now i am getting the reservation before the time which i have passed for the same date.Please help..

```
 @GET
        @Path("/getReservationByUserIdAndTypeAndDateTime/{userid}/{type}/{date}/{time}")
        public List<Reservation> getReservationByAndUserIdAndTypeAndDateTime(@PathParam("userid") int uid, @PathParam("type") int tid,@PathParam("date") Date date,@PathParam("time") Time time) {
            CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Reservation> criteria = builder.createQuery(Reservation.class);
            Root<Reservation> r = criteria.from(Reservation.class);
            TypedQuery<Reservation> query = em.createQuery(
                criteria.select(r).where(new Predicate[]{
                        builder.equal(r.get(Reservation_.usersId), uid), 
                        builder.equal(r.get(Reservation_.reservationsType), tid),

                        builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(builder.concat(r.get(Reservation_.date), " "+r.get(Reservation_.time)), date.toString()+" "+time.toString())}));
            return query.getResultList();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please show the mapping for the `date` and `time` fields of the `Reservation` class?

Comment: I have just simply added thetwo fields.. date and time as String and created getters and setters..

Comment: @Column(nullable=false, length=10)
 private String date;

Answer (score 1):

Comparing dates and times formatted as string is not advisable, results can depend on the format. It would be better having a unique `Date` field in the `Reservation` class:

```
@Temporal(TIMESTAMP) Date date;
```

and using date comparison in the query:

```
 builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(r.get(Reservation_.date), date)
```

This way the `time` parameter in the `getReservationByAndUserIdAndTypeAndDateTime` method can be omitted, since the `date` parameter would hold both date and time.